# how to get digits of 1000 numbers using a function in excel?

Tags: excel

I have a column in excel(assume column A) that contains 1000 numbers. I want to get digits of any number and add them all.

I know that I can type =LEN(A1) in B1 cell and drag it up to the B1000 cell to get digits of all numbers and then add them. but I want to type a formula in A1001 cell(just below last cell) that does that for me. one way is to type =SUM(LEN(A1), LEN(A2), LEN(A3),...) and separate every LEN with a comma. but for 1000 numbers it's impossible. I tried to type =SUM(LEN(A1:A1000)) but it shows "#VALUE!" in the A1001 cell. is there any approach to do that?

Comment: Try sumproduct instead of sum or enter your current formula through control+shift+enter

Comment: @JvdV: many thanks it solved my problem.